# Create customer address in magento2 by customerId

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-address

I am using below code to create customer address using customerId

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');
$address = $addresss->create();

$address->setCustomerId(1256)
        ->setFirstname('test')
        ->setLastname('test')
        ->setCountryId('GB')
        ->setPostcode('NW p7j')
        ->setCity('test')
        ->setTelephone('1232323')
        ->setStreet('test')
        ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
        try{
            $address->save();
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
        }
```

I have two lines for street, how can i set that?  Right now street is storing with one line. also how can we update address if that customer already has any address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');
$address = $addresss->create();

$address->setCustomerId(3)
        ->setFirstname('test')
        ->setLastname('test')
        ->setCountryId('GB')
        ->setPostcode('NW p7j')
        ->setCity('test')
        ->setTelephone('1232323')
        ->setStreet(['test','test2'])
        ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
        try{
            $address->save();
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
        }
?>
```

You need to pass array to street like my answer to save it in street, street1, street2 etc.

**UPDATED ANSWER:**
If you have $line = 'test'; and $line2 = 'test' then try the below code for street

```
->setStreet([$line,$line2])
```

Comment: Do i need to use setData if i store test and test2 into some variables?
if i have like $line = 'test';$line2 = 'test';

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Okay, i will check it, if line2 is empty does it works?

Comment: Yes then it will set blank value.

Comment: Nice, Its working great!!!

Comment: But issue with region, i tried below code to set region
$address->setRegion('Surflock'); it is not saving

Comment: https://vinothkumaarr.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/add-customer-and-address-programmatically-magento2/ check this.

Comment: Use setRegion('Test') for text type and for dropdown use setRegionId(1).

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the database structure of Magento 2, you will find that for a customer address entity, there is only one attribute for storing street.

Please look into the table **`eav_attribute`** and search for attribute code like %street%.

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE '%street%'
```

You will find only one record having the **attribute_code** **`street`**.

Hence, to store the street value from two input boxes, first, you need to concatenate both values and then store the result for the attribute street.

Next, to update an already existing address, you need to write:

```
$address->setId(your_current_address_entity_id);
```

before `$address->save();`

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: i do not have any address_entity_id, have only customerId, using that i need to update if he has any address

Answer (score 1):

***I Did check and its working proper***

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');

        $address = $addresss->create();

        $address->setCustomerId($customerId)

            ->setFirstname($FirstName)

            ->setLastname($LastName)

            ->setCountryId($countryid)

            ->setPostcode($postcode)

            ->setCity($city)

            ->setTelephone($telephone)

            ->setFax($fax)

            ->setCompany($Company)

            ->setStreet($Street)

            ->setRegion($region)

            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

        $address->save();
```

***And if you want to set default billing & shipping address just add 2 line like below***

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');

        $address = $addresss->create();

        $address->setCustomerId($customerId)

            ->setFirstname($FirstName)

            ->setLastname($LastName)

            ->setCountryId($countryid)

            ->setPostcode($postcode)

            ->setCity($city)

            ->setTelephone($telephone)

            ->setFax($fax)

            ->setCompany($Company)

            ->setStreet($Street)

            ->setRegion($region)

            ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')

            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')

            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

        $address->save();
```

Comment: Its working good

Comment: Thanks for this code